# como pega um valor do jquery e guarda em uma variavel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estou querendo fazer uma soma de todas a notas com `input`, adicionados pelo `JQuery`,só que não consigo pega valores do `JQuery` quando eu aperto no botão `+`, queria saber como posso pega os valores do `JQuery` quando eu aperto no botão mais e digito um número,para colocar esse valor em uma variável.

[[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sup>Click para ver a imagem em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtGqw.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ex001</title>
  <script src=" https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .qtd {
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
  </style>



</head>

<body>
  <h2>Média de notas</h2>


  <div id="form">
    <input type='number' class="qt" id="qt1" placeholder="Nota">

    <input type="button" class='botão' id="b" value="+">




    <input type="button" class='finalizar' value='Finalizar' onclick="finalizar()">



    <script>
      $('#b').click(function() {
        var gua = $('#form').append('<input type="text" class="qta" id="qtd" placeholder="Nota"> ').val()
        window.alert(gua)



      })

      function finalizar() {





      }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: valeu mano,estava procurando errado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para pegar o valor de um `input` com o `JQuery` basta utilizar a função [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
const valor = $('#qt1').val();
```

No seu caso deduzo que o botão `+` não irá ler o valor e sim adicionar um novo `input` e você só irá ler o valor no botão `finalizar`. Tendo isso em mente, provavelmente seria mais fácil percorrer todos os `inputs` com a classe `qt` e utilizar os valores obtidos para fazer o cálculo. Vou adaptar seu código utilizando essa forma:

```js
const adicionar = () => $('#form').append('<input type="number" class="qt" placeholder="Nota" />');

const finalizar = () => {
  const valores = $('.qt')
    .map((indice, elemento) => parseInt($(elemento).val(), 10))
    .get();

  const soma = valores.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  const media = (soma / valores.length) || 0;

  console.log(`Média: ${media}`);
};

const inicializar = () => {
  adicionar();
  $('#btnAdicionar').click(adicionar);
  $('#btnFinalizar').click(finalizar);
};

$(document).ready(inicializar);
```

```css
input {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

div#form {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Média de notas</h2>
<div id="form"></div>
<input type="button" id="btnAdicionar" value="+" />
<input type="button" id='btnFinalizar' value='Finalizar' />
```